# plot element of a list

Tags: r, list, plot

I'm learning to work with lists in R, I looked in the internet and in some books but I did not find out the solution. 
I have a data frame with n rows and several columns. What I would like to do is a simple and quickly way to plot one column (e.g. value1) for each year (other column).

First, I created a list from a data.frame using, split

```
lst<-split(X, X$Year)
```

So now I have a subset of data frame divided for years, and that's fine.
But now, how can I create now plot of value1 for each year?
I tried to write a short script, but it doesn't work at all

```
lst<-split(X, X$Year)
for (i in names(lst)) {
  plot(i$value1)
}
```

Comment: I don't think I understand what you mean by plotting one column for each year. Do you mean each year should have a different line in the plot? If so, what should be on the x axis? Can you provide a reproducible subset of your data using `dput(head(mydata))` (or perhaps something like `dput(head(mydata, 30))` to get more rows, some from each year)?

Comment: Some books? Can you name one?

Comment: X axis should show only the frequency of value1.

Comment: Shouldn't you be looping like this: `for( i in 1:(length(lst)) plot(lst[[ii]]$value1` ?

Comment: Books: R graphics, R in a Nutshell and some websites

Comment: It is unclear what you want, a single plot or many?  I'd look to `ggplot2`:  `ggplot(X, aex(x=value1, color=Year)) + geom_bar()` or something like that.

Comment: @Carl, I tried but I receive an error: Error: unexpected symbol in "for( i in 1:(length(lst)) plot"

Comment: In all honesty, it's beginning to look like you need to run thru the "Introduction to R"-type websites and learn the basics of the syntax and object types. It doesn't seem that you understand how to write commands in R all that well.

Comment: @Carl Thanks for the suggestion. I'll do that

Comment: possible duplicate of [plot data with different dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364435/plot-data-with-different-dates)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are after:

```
library(xts)
data<-xts(data.frame(a=c(1,2,3), b=c(4,5,6)), c(as.POSIXct("1970-01-01"), as.POSIXct("1971-01-01"), as.POSIXct("1972-01-01")))
plot(data[,1], ylim=c(min(data), max(data)))
for (i in 2:ncol(data)) { 
    lines(data[,i]) 
}
```

Crude but works...